# Adding SASL Authentication in Kafka Banzai

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, apache-kafka, sasl

I am looking to add SASL Plaintext authentication in Banzai Kafka. I have added following configs in my read only config section.

```
  readOnlyConfig: |
    auto.create.topics.enable=false
    cruise.control.metrics.topic.auto.create=true
    cruise.control.metrics.topic.num.partitions=1
    cruise.control.metrics.topic.replication.factor=2
    delete.topic.enable=true
    offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
    group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=3000

    sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
    sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256
    listener.name.external.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="user" password="testuser";
```

I have scripted following in listener config

```
listenersConfig:
    externalListeners:
      - type: "sasl_plaintext"
        name: "external"
        externalStartingPort: 51985
        containerPort: 29094
        accessMethod: LoadBalancer
    internalListeners:
      - type: "plaintext"
        name: "internal"
        containerPort: 29092
        usedForInnerBrokerCommunication: true
      - type: "plaintext"
        name: "controller"
        containerPort: 29093
        usedForInnerBrokerCommunication: false
        usedForControllerCommunication: true
```

When I try to connect producer or consumer - kafka returns Authentication Authorization failed error.

I am setting following properties:

```
session.timeout.ms=60000 
partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.StickyAssignor 
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT 
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256 
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="user" password="testuser";
```

Can any one suggest on this?

Comment: Please show your client code and how you added certificates/JAAS options to it

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer.

I am setting following properties:

session.timeout.ms=60000
partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.StickyAssignor
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="user" password="testuser";

Comment: I'm not sure about authentication, but if the _authorization_ failed, sounds like you need to configure ACLs

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer for reply. Can you please suggest what shell I add in my config to enable SASL authentication and authorization?

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't use banzai operator, but your client configs seem fine without knowing how your certificates get created. Maybe try creating a github issue https://github.com/banzaicloud/kafka-operator/issues